# Passar Controls para uma função

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Eu tenho uma interface em Visual C#. Nessa interface tenho uma Classe chamada T50 que contem todas as variável que preciso.

Já implementei um botão em que salvo o objeto criado pela classe T50. Consigo salvar e ler esse objeto (Usando serialize).

Só que quando releio um objeto salvo eu preciso preencher a parte da interface que o usuário já tinha preenchido.

Dentro do minha classe T50 existe uma função para fazer isso.

```
private void button_t50_carregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Código de ler o dado

        // Usa uma função para preencher os dados
        T50_Data.PreencheInterface(T50_Data);
    }
```

Só que dentro dessa função eu preciso acessar todos os Controls da minha Form para ajustá-los(Button, Textbox, DataGridViwe....).

Sei como recebe-los individualmente, por exemplo

```
public void PreencheInterface (T50 T50Data, TextBox text)
{
}
```

Existe uma forma de eu passar todos eles ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Estás a usar `WPF` ou `Windows Forms` ?

Comment: Estou usando Windows Forms. Mas meu conhecimento não e muito avançado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você poderia fazer assim:

Passar seu `Form` para o método:

```
public void Metodo(NomeDoForm form)
{
    form.Controls["btnEsc"].Text = "Escape";
}
```

E dentro do método chamar cada componente do form usando o `form.Controls["NomeComponente"]`.

E depois só chamar o método no `Form` passando o `this`, que seria o próprio formulário.

Answer (score 2):

A função PreencheInterface poderia receber o objeto do formulário (https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.form(v=vs.110).aspx) e iterar sobre a coleção de controles dentro do formulário (https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/4z8d1tx5(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
private void button_t50_carregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Obtém o formulário do botão clicado
        // (supondo que o form é o controle pai imediato do botão
        Form formulario = (Form)((sender as Button).Parent)

        // Código de ler o dado

        // Usa uma função para preencher os dados
        T50_Data.PreencheInterface(formulario);
    }
```

Comment: Seria o objeto de toda a Form1? Mas como eu passo esse objeto para ela. Isso que não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Você pode utilizar o atributo "parent" do button (até alcançar o form)  e fazer seu cast para o tipo form. Melhorei a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

consegui resolver o problema reunindo as informações de todos. Obrigado ao @MeuChapeu e @rocmartins. Vou deixar a minha solução aqui para futuras dúvidas.

O problema era que a minha Form1 é composta por uma TapPage, dentro de outra TabPage, e alguns botões ainda estão dentro de um GroupBox. A partir desse botão para voltar até a Form1, tive que fazer:

```
Form formulario = (Form)((((((((((sender as Button).Parent) as TabPage).Parent) as TabControl).Parent) as TabPage).Parent) as TabControl).Parent);
```

Assim posso passar esse "formulario" para meu método. E para acessar um botão que esteja dentro de um GroupBox que esteja nessa Tabpage:

```
form.Controls["TabControl1"].Controls["TabPage1"].Controls["TabControl2"].Controls["groupBox1"].Controls["button"].Text = "Novo Texto Botão".
```

Obrigado pela ajuda!